# Longest chain of letters in word JavaScript

Tags: javascript, find, cpu-word, chain, letter

I need to write a program that is find longest chain of letters in a word and displays it in a console.log with their length. Example aaaAAAAdddeess - console.log( 'AAAA' ,4 ). Program must be in JavaScript and must distinguish capital letters. I`ve tried something like

```js
const word = 'aaadddAAAwwwweee'

let newWord = ' '

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

  if (word[i] === word[i + 1]) {

    newWord += word[i] + word[i + 1]

    i++

  }

}

console.log(newWord, newWord.lenght)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271856/understanding-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm

Comment: @Dalorzo How is a search algorithm relevant for this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the longest substring that consists of the same char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907202/how-to-find-the-longest-substring-that-consists-of-the-same-char)

Comment: I`m still dont undestand it. Im  weak in working with strings. I`ve tried to slice it to an array and then checking values but it wont works. Are you know a solution i javascript for this ?

Comment: Yes it is thanks. Now i need to display it and it will be done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the word to letters and check each letter with next one. Then push current sequence in an array, it will be current max sequence. Each iteration check the size of current longest sequnece with max sequence.

```js
  const word = 'aaadddAAAwwwweee'

  let lettersArr = word.split('');
  let currentSequence = [];
  let maxSequence = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < lettersArr.length; index++) {
      let element = lettersArr[index];
      currentSequence = [element];

      for (let i = index + 1; i < lettersArr.length; i++) {
          if (lettersArr[index] == lettersArr[i]) {
              currentSequence.push(lettersArr[index]);
          } else {
              break;
          }
      }

      if (currentSequence.length > maxSequence.length) {
          maxSequence = currentSequence;
      }
  }

  let newWord = maxSequence.join('');

  console.log(newWord, newWord.length);
```